# Why did it ask me to add curly braces before @override? This wasn't required in the tutorial

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The second image is the one without curly braces, and it marks that area with a red line.
The first image has curly braces inserted in it, and the line disappeared. Why was there a need to add curly braces?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I tried without the curly braces as shown in the tutorial, but it showed error.

Comment: You are missing semicolon. So, please add after completion of your QuoteCard constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
class QuoteCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuoteCard({super.key}) <-- missing semi colon here
```

you are missing a semi colon after the constructor, a curly brace is not required before the override annotation.

Comment: ohh thanks a lot, I somehow missed that part.

Comment: no problem, could you please mark this is as the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Use key with the contructor and end the line by using semicolon like this:

> const QuoteCard({super.key, required this.quote});

2. Then there is no error before the @override

[image]